# Phpmailer doesn´t work with simpleSAML installed

Tags: phpmailer, simplesamlphp

I have a website sending veirified emails with **phpMailer**. I just installed **simplesamlphp** at server in order to validate users with SAML 2.0. Now i can´t send emails (that where working fine til installation).

I tried setting **$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";** but it´s not working.

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message
>   'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php:1678
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1540):
>   PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1335):
>   PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Wed, 24 A...', 'postSend() #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/smydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/alta_convocatoria.php(676):
>   PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 1678

Any clue?

Comment: This needs more info. What port number are you connecting to?

Comment: Ok, i fount it, just remove: $mail->IsSMTP(); when checking the SMTP class the SAML blocks it.

Comment: If you don't call `isSMTP`, PHPMailer doesn't use SMTP at all, but uses the `mail()` function, which is slower and less safe. Why should SAML block SMTP?